# Comparing derived class, to interface - unintended comparison

Tags: c#

I have this suggestion popping up in my editor, but not entirely sure why it is uncomfortable with my comparison.

I have a class called `Item` and this has an interface `IInteract` to represent the item can be picked up.

I also have a `Slot` class which has `IInteract` to allow me to place items.

So i create collection of all nearby interactions and I am checking if one of them is an `Item`

```
    // Item:IInteract
    // _interactables is a List<IInteract>()

    public void RemoveFromNearBy(Item item)
    {
        _interactables.Remove(item);

        // Possible unintended reference comparison
        // cast RHS to object

        if (item == _nearestInteraction)
            _nearestInteraction = null;
    }
```

Why does this comparison suggest to cast to object? What is the common mistake people make in order for this warning to prop up ? Currently i am not seeing what issues could arise by ignoring it?

Comment: Is `_nearestInteraction` of type `IInteract`? Does `Item` overload `==`? Most importantly, is a reference comparison intended here?

Comment: Equality comparisons are tricky. Make `IInteract` require that the class implement `IEquatable` (and implement it in each class) and you should be good to go